# Error Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.wallet.publicKey.toBuffer'), when using Metaplex with Bundlr

Tags: metaplex-js, keypair, bundlr

I am making a call to metaplex.nfts().uploadMetadata and using the keypairIdentity with a Solana id.json file. I believe this issue is in the Bundlr code but not sure why. Is anyone else using a Solana json wallet file with Bundlr? Here's my setup.

```
    const node_env = process.env.NODE_ENV;
    console.log("NODE_ENV", node_env);
    const conn = new Connection(
      node_env === development
        ? clusterApiUrl("devnet")
        : clusterApiUrl("mainnet-beta")
    );
    const userKeypair = await createSolanaKeypairFromFile();
    console.log("wallet pubkey", userKeypair.publicKey.toBase58());
    const providerUrl =
      node_env === development
        ? "https://api.devnet.solana.com"
        : "https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com";
    console.log("providerUrl", providerUrl);
    const mplex = Metaplex.make(conn)
      .use(keypairIdentity(userKeypair))
      .use(
        bundlrStorage({
          address:
            node_env === development
              ? "https://devnet.bundlr.network"
              : "https://node2.bundlr.network",
          providerUrl,
          timeout: 60000,
        })
      );
    this.client = mplex.nfts(); // *** notice this.client represents mplex.nfts() ***
  }

  const { uri } = await this.client
      ?.uploadMetadata({
        name,
      })
      .run()
      .catch((err: any) => {
        console.log("uploadMetadata", err);
      });
```

Here's the error stack
[image]